# CSP - Whitelist Content Location: does it work for a site that has tracking and affiliate marketing in it

Tags: whitelist, affiliate, content-security-policy

CSP uses a whitelist of domains that can host content.

Can this work with a site that uses affiliate marketing? Typically on an "order completed" page there is an iframe that hosts a script that is in controll of an affiliate partner.

It would be ok to whitelist the domain of the affiliate-script, but I am in no controll of what the script does: I am pretty shure it will load other content that is not whitelistet.

Does anybody have good or bad experience with affiliate scripts and CSP?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to this article you have to whitelist every single source you load scripts from. Every source for every kind of data.

http://www.domblogger.net/Security/CSP

The affiliate script stuff (i've seen so far) never calls scripts from 2nd+ level locations. The scripts do requests to process data on server side and there are redirects of those request to get cookies to your browser for example.

Technically you could run affiliate stuff with unknown sources with 'unsafe-inline'. But thats not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ad providers are not always trusted, due to resale of ad space you can end up displaying ads of ad networks you don't deal with directly and potentially execute malware on your clients.

Regarding CSP: If you punch too many holes into the rules it will become useless.
That being said, there are several things you can do, for one: [sandbox the iframe](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/)

Alternatively you could only allow advertisements that use a safe subset of JavaScript (this check can be performed statically). "Safe" means that the `document` object will not be modified etc. - the client should remain unaffected even if the ad network is malicious.

A promiment example is [ADsafe](http://www.adsafe.org/), but there are other options.